# С мобильного интернета не могу пользоваться приложениями от Google и загружать с браузера

Tags: android

Когда сижу на мобильном интернете Play Marker не грузит ничего (пишет что нету инета) также как и YouTube

- Не могу скачивать (тож ничего) с браузера(Диспетчер загрузки пишет "  <Без названия>  Не удалось загрузить файл")
- Могу сидеть в Inst или в браузере

Но при включении  VPN всё нормально функционирует как и с WiFi.

Страна: Україна

Comment: Какая страна/область/штат?

Comment: была такая проблема. Один с провайдеров почему то решил выдавать IP адреса, которые были в Крымском пуле. А гугл их особо не фильтровал. И готово. Лечится обращением к провайдеру (мобильному). А у другого провайдера (мобильного) совершенно случайно траффик ходил через Россию и там его банил РКН.